# Why the "meat" in "sweetmeat"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, compounds

This has always confused me.  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sweetmeat) doesn't help at all.  Candy and meat just don't go together that well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key is that *meat* used to just mean "food". The first entry under [*meat* at Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meat) has exactly that definition, though of course the primary sense of *meat* today is  definition #2, which specifically refers to animal flesh. However, the older, broader sense of "meat" still sticks around here and there, such as the practice of referring to the edible part of a nut as the "meat", and in compounds such as "sweetmeat".

Comment: Ok, now explain "sweetbread" meaning meat o_O

Comment: @Karl Knechtel One of the meanings of _bread_ is "a piece or morsel of food."

Comment: @kiamlaluno and *brede* means "roasted meat" while Old English *bræd* means "meat" or "flesh",

Comment: My grandmother would make "mincemeat pie" which confused us (her grandchildren) when we were little, because it had no meat in it...

Comment: @GEdgar a seasonal classic, though still (unless matters changed recently) illegal to eat around late December under laws passed during the Interregnum banning many Christmas traditions and later ignored rather than repealed.

Answer (score 2):

The OED reports the following definitions for *meat* (I report the first two):

> 1. Food; nourishment for people or animals; especially solid food, as opposite to drink. Now archaic and dialectal. OE.
>
> > S. Johnson: The horses could not travel all day without rest or meat.
> >     Shelley: He had… meat and drink enough.
> >     Proverb: One man's meat is another man's poison.
> >
> > A kind of food, an article of food. Obsolete except in *sweetmeat*. OE.